# Time series regression - RandomForest

Tags: scikit-learn, time-series, regression, random-forest

Apologies for the dumb questions - total n00b here.

Let's say I have the following dataset.

```
date,site,category,locale,type,rank,sessions,logins
01/01/2017,google.com,search,US,free,1,3393093,50000
01/01/2017,google.com,overall,US,free,1,3393093,50000
01/01/2017,yahoo.com,search,US,3,free,core,393093,40000
01/01/2017,yahoo.com,news,US,9,free,393093,40000
01/01/2017,yahoo.com,overall,US,23,free,393093,40000
01/01/2017,wsj.com,news,US,21,free,200000,180000
01/01/2017,wsj.com,news,US,21,subscription,200000,180000
01/01/2017,wsj.com,overall,US,93,free,200000,180000
```

where rank is the Alexa rank of that site. There are several categories possible (search, email, e-commerce etc) and the rank corresponds to the rank within that category.

I am trying to predict the number of sessions and logins a particular site/locale/rank would have for a particular day, essentially boiling this down to a multivariate time series regression problem and I am using sklearn's RandomForestRegressor.

Right now I don't treat this as a time series problem at all - for training, I remove the `date` and `site` columns, encode the `category`, `locale` and `rank` columns, use them and `rank` as inputs and train my model to predict `sessions` and `logins`. The results look decent but I wanted to know:

1. How could this be converted into a proper time series prediction? I saw [some examples by Jason Brownlee](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-supervised-learning/) where the problem was reframed as a supervised learning problem - but this wouldn't work as I have potentially millions of rows of training data. I could group the training data by category/locale/type, sort by date and for testing at day T for a particular category/locale/type combination, use data up to day T-1 for training - but this approach would be very expensive as there are potentially thousands of such category/locale/type combinations
2. I've read about using moving averages to boost performance. Calculating the moving averages of `sessions` and `logins` in the training set would be trivial, but since this is a dependent variable, how would I capture this in the test set?
3. Is there a better tool than RF for this task?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the method in the linked blog post, the data transformation shouldn't be a problem if you use vectorized numpy operations like `shift`.

By the way if you just ignore the date, you're just calcuating the average numbers for each group, i.e. you're using a random forest to build a very fancy pivot-table ;-)

Comment: Thanks but the`shift` method involves creating a column for each row. Seeing that there are around a million rows, that would result in a million+ columns - I'm not sure about the efficiency there

Comment: you don't do a column for each row, you just do a few steps within a window size (in the linked blog post they just use the previous time step for each row)